# getting data from firebase but face Index error

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers, indexof, android-maps

I want to display user name, but face index issues. All the markers show the same text.

I initialize the value of `i` on the top with `0`. What can I do the line `userbattery.setText("user battery:" + fcmUsers.get(i-1).Battery.toString());` that can display all the markers value separately?

```
 DatabaseReference UserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("GPSLocationHistory").child("DevicesLatest");
    UserRef.keepSynced(true);
    new GetDataFromFirebase().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);


    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    //  myRef = database.getReference("GPSLocationHistory/DevicesLatest");


    UserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            latLngList.clear();
            mMap.clear();
            if (marker != null) {
                marker.remove();
            }
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Iterator<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshots = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
             fcmUsers = new ArrayList<>();
             i = 0;
            while (dataSnapshots.hasNext()) {
                DataSnapshot dataSnapshotChild = dataSnapshots.next();
                ModelClassFireBase fcmUser = dataSnapshotChild.getValue(ModelClassFireBase.class);
                fcmUsers.add(fcmUser);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(fcmUsers.get(i).lati.toString()), Double.parseDouble(fcmUsers.get(i).longi.toString())); // Use your server's methods
                latLngList.add(latLng);
                mark1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(fcmUsers.get(i).Battery.toString()).position(latLngList.get(i)));//.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.female4)));
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), uniqueids.get(i).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                markerList.add(mark1);


                i++;

                if (fcmUsers.size() > 0) {

                } else {
                    // Display dialog for there is no user available.
                }

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // for handling database error
        }
    });
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

            // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_widow_layout, null);

            // Getting the position from the marker
            LatLng latLng = arg0.getPosition();

            // Getting reference to the TextView to set latitude
            TextView userbattery = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lat);

            // Getting reference to the TextView to set longitude
           // TextView tvLng = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lng);
           // ImageView userimage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.userimage);


            userbattery.setText("user battery:" + fcmUsers.get(i-1).Battery.toString());

            return v;

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I initialize the value of i on the top with 0

Well, don't. Having an index as a member variable of the class wasn't the correct idea

(similar things can be said for `mark1` variable)

Firebase executes when it can at any unknown point in time.

Your code, on the other hand executes practically immediately, so `i - 1 = 0 - 1 = -1`, and no list has a negative position. And no, setting `i = 1`, is not a solution.

---

If I understand the current code correctly, you're only going to  get the very last object in the list...

```
if(!fcmUsers.isEmpty()) {
    ModelClassFireBase last =  fcmUsers.get(fcmUsers.length() - 1);
    userbattery.setText(String.valueOf(last.getBattery()));
}
```

**If that isn't the intended result**, then you have a whole `fcmUsers` list, but only one map info window, so there's only one value to set if you use the `i` variable, and you're not setting one *per object*, which explains why all the values are the same.

You can either use the `position` variable in place of `i - 1`, or, like any adapter in android, get the data about the element at the current position from the Marker that's provided

```
userbattery.setText("user battery:" + arg0.getTitle());
```

---

Also, don't forget to move `if (fcmUsers.size() > 0)` outside the while loop

Comment: no i donot want to get last object from the list i want that when user click on the marker it shows the battery of the marker(from the fcUsers list)
it is a tracking application

Comment: every marker have separate values i simply want to display on the markers

Comment: You already did `MarkerOptions().title(fcmUsers.get(i)` when you added the marker, so why do you think you need to get it again from the users list?

Comment: want to set userbattery.setText(String.valueOf(last.Battery));

with valid index from the fcmUser

Comment: ModelClassFireBase last =  fcmUsers.get(fcmUsers.length() - 1);

This code will set the last value on every markers but i want to set its own value on every marker on click

Comment: Did you try to use `arg0.getTitle()`?

Comment: yes its work but fcmUsers list have 

public Long  Battery;
    public Long createdat;
    public Long hajjappnum;
    public Long  id;
    public Long lati;
    public Long longi;
    public Long uniqueID;

these values how can i use these on the textView

Advance thanks brother

Comment: for example i want to set hajjappnum on this text field what i can do?

Comment: i want to get data from the fcmUsers List to show on the markers

Comment: You can accept this post and create a new one asking specifically for that since I've answered the immediate question

Comment: I'd be happy to help on another post, but I've given enough details already here, that I think you should try to accomplish that on your own first

Comment: what do you mean i donot understand it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219465/index-value-issue-on-the-markers

@cricket_007 answer on it

Comment: Ohh i will

now please help me what i can do?